# Matlab column aggregation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, aggregation

Is there a function in MATLAB which allows to aggregate (or we can say sum) columns in a matrix per defined number of columns?

For example I have:

```
A =

 1     2     3     4     5     6
 9    10    11    12    13    14
17    18    19    20    21    22
```

I wish to aggregate every 2 columns, like this: `col1+col2`, and then `col3+col4`, and then `col5+col6`, so my output is:

```
A_agg =

 3     7    11
19    23    27
35    39    43
```

I couldn't find a built-in function and was trying to write a `for` loop but I couldn't manage to do it since I am quite new to programming. Do you have any suggestions/solutions how this could be solved with a `for` loop, or maybe there is a built-in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `mat2cell` and `cellfun`.  You can use `mat2cell` to split up your matrices into individual 2 column chunks. Each chunk would be stored as a cell in a cell array.  You can then use `cellfun` to take each cell and sum row-wise.  After you're done, you can use `cell2mat` to convert back.

Using your example:

```
A = [1:6;9:14;17:22];
B = mat2cell(A, 3, [2 2 2]);
C = cellfun(@(x) sum(x,2), B, 'UniformOutput', false);
A_agg = cell2mat(C);
```

`A_agg` should thus give you:

```
A_agg =

 3     7    11
19    23    27
35    39    43
```

Let's walk through the code slowly:

`A` is defined as we had before.  `B` will be a cell array, and will segment your matrix into matrices of 2 columns per cell.  The first parameter is the matrix you want to decompose (in our case `A`).  The second parameter tells you how many rows each segment should have.  Because we want all of the matrices to have the same number of rows, we thus supply one number which is `3`.  After, you specify the number of columns you want per matrix.  Because there are 6 columns, we need 3 matrices, and so you'd specify a vector of `[2 2 2]`.

`C` is the output of `cellfun`, where `cellfun` applies a function to every single element in a cell matrix.  What you want to do here is for each cell (essentially each matrix), you want to sum row-wise.  The first parameter is an anonymous function that takes in a matrix from each cell, and sums row-wise.  The second parameter is the cell array we just created.  You'll notice that we have an additional flag to set: `UniformOutput`.  The reason why you have to set `UniformOutput = false` is because if you apply `cellfun` without that flag, the expected result at the end of the function you apply to each cell is scalar.  Because we are outputting a **column vector** instead, we have to set this flag to false.

`A_agg` will thus aggregate all of your cells back to matrix form.

If you want to do this for any size matrix, bear in mind that there has to be an even amount of columns for this work.  What I mean by even is that the number of columns has to be evenly divisible by 2.  You would thus re-run the code like so:

```
B = mat2cell(A, size(A,1), 2*ones(1, size(A,2)/2));
C = cellfun(@(x) sum(x,2), B, 'UniformOutput', false);
A_agg = cell2mat(C);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this one worked well for me with the example, for some reason I had to add: `C = cellfun(@(x) sum(x,2), B, 'UniformOutput',false);`  the only issue is that I have a matrix that is 1750x250 and I want to resize it to 1750x50, but it is not even, is there any solution for odd matrix ?

Comment: OH YES.  I forgot about that.  Let me add that into my code.  As for your resizing, I'm not quite sure I follow.  With the code that I have, it will reduce your matrix to 1750 x 125.  Why would you need it to be 50?  Do you want to aggregate over every **five** columns?  If you do, that's a very easy fix.  Simply change the `B` to this:  `B = mat2cell(A, size(A,1), 5*ones(1, size(A,2)/5));`

Comment: FWIW: The reason why you have to add `UniformOutput = false` is because if you apply `cellfun` without that flag, the expected result at the end of the function you apply to it is scalar.  Because we are outputting a **column vector** instead, we have to set this flag to false.  I'll edit my post.  Nice spot!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you wrote previously about even amount of columns. I run your code now and it worked perfectly for me! thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, please consider accepting one of our answers if it helped you out.

Answer (score 4):

Since `sum` operates down columns in a matrix, I first reshape `A` so that it has 2 rows and 9 columns, then sum down each column. Then reshape back to the desired output matrix `A_agg`.

```
A=[1  2  3  4  5  6
   9  10 11 12 13 14 
   17 18 19 20 21 22]

[m,n]=size(A);
A_agg=reshape(sum(reshape(A',2,[])),m,[])'
```

Comment: Nice job on `reshape`.  Never thought to `reshape` it in that fashion! +1

Comment: @David Thanks for this simple and very effective solution it worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This is probably faster than using `cellfun`. +1

Comment: @LuisMendo: I agree.  I couldn't see how to do it using `reshape` so I defaulted to segmenting the matrix into cells and working on each cell individually.  That's what's great about SO.  You teach people some things, and you also learn new tricks along the way!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, is to use [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html). Let `n` denote the number of columns to be aggregated (`2` in your example). Then:

```
A_agg = blockproc(A, [size(A,1) n], @(x) sum(x.data, 2));
```